# Azure DevOps Artifacts - How to publish the build artifact to azure artifact feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have dotnet build pipeline where i am doing multiple steps like shown in below image. at the end of the building and running unit test i am publishing the artifacts using **publish build artifacts** task which by default saves the artifact under drop folder in the artifacts for each build. But i want to save this artifact to Feed so that it is available for everyone. How can i do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Publish a package

To publish packages to an Azure Artifacts feed from your pipeline, you must set the Project Collection Build Service identity to be a Contributor on your feed. See [Configure feed settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#configure-feed-settings) for more details.

```
steps:
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'NuGet Authenticate'
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: '<projectName>/<feed>'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-a-package